# What's the common phrase for "... tell you in a better moment"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

I thought [tell you in a better moment](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22tell%20you%20in%20a%20better%20moment%22&*) was the correct phrase, but Google disagrees.

What the common/idiomatic version?

Example sentence:

> She wanted to confess her affair to her husband. However, she didn't
>   want to tell him now. She wanted to tell him __

Comment: She wanted to "wait for the right moment"? "... proper timing"? "... right time"?

Comment: @shin so "tell you at the right moment"?

Comment: @Shin That has got to be an answer!

Comment: "at a more opportune time"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We often say "tell you when the time is right".

Here are [some examples from Google books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGGE_en-gbGB422GB422&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=613&tbm=bks&q=%22tell+you+when+the+time+is+right%22&oq=%22tell+you+when+the+time+is+right%22&gs_l=serp.3..30i10k1.6803.7771.0.8764.3.3.0.0.0.0.101.248.2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.3.246.H41vxWUapUk).

In the Original Poster's sentence we could say:

> She wanted to confess her affair to her husband. However, she didn't want to tell him now. She wanted to tell him when the time was right.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with Araucaria's answer. But in case you really want to use the sentence  "*tell you in a better moment*", you could say:

> She wanted to confess her affair to her husband. However, she didn't want to tell him now. She wanted to **tell him in a better time**.

This is grammatically correct, because in the phrase "*tell you in a better moment*" the word "*you*" is an **object pronoun** referring to the third person and can the replaced for "*me*", "*him*", "*her*", "*us*" or "*them*" according to the context.